# import images from a 3rd party system via api

Tags: api

Before I start pulling my hair out with this one as I think its going to be a complicated one I would really appreciate someones advice.

i try to import image to  magento store but i don't know how.
so i want  to create plugin to import images from a 3rd party system via web service .

0
down vote
favorite
1
How do you import product images from a CSV file using System > Import/Export > Import?

I've followed suggestions from various sources but nothing works. This is the format of the CSV file:

"sku","image","small_image","thumbnail"
90048,"test.jpg","test.jpg","test.jpg"

how can i do it?

Would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

the data looks right but make sure that the csv file has proper line breaks("CRLF") or Magento will no be able to parse the file, if possible try creating the file using a with excel or an application similar.

Also the images by default have to be located in the /media/import if Magento doesn't find the images then, it won't assigned the value and it will give an "images not found" error instead.